# Google Apps Script - Failed to send a request

Tags: post, google-apps-script, flask-restful

I need a help.
I have a **Flask API** running like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/rules/<payload>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_none(payload):
    return jsonify({'result': payload})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

My **Google code** is trying to send a post request, but always I got an **invalid request**.
I ran the same request using Postman and I didn't get the error. I don't understand what's happening.

```
rulesArray = [{'column_a': 35.0, 'column_b': 100.0, 'column_c': 105.0}, {'column_a': 38.0, 'column_b': 50.0, 'column_c': 80.0}];

var payload = {'content': rulesArray};
var params = { method: "POST", payload: payload, muteHttpExceptions: true, contentType: "application/json" };

var URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/rules';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, params);
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Apps Script cannot directly access your local server (ip address 127.0.0.1:5000). You're going to have to host it so that it is publicly accessible from the web.

Comment: OK... Thanks a lot!
I was thinking to test it locally, but what you commented makes a lot of sense.